# Focus on input field but do not show keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile, web-applications

is there any way to set focus on the input field without showing keyboard on a device? The code is shared across the website and the mobile device. I just want to acquire situation when on a website I got "focus" on the input element as well as on device but without displaying a keyboard on the device. I tried:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").focus();
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: please explain, why would you do that?

Comment: Because focusing on website avoids clicking by the mouse on the input. On the device, keyboard covers too much space (which restricting usability) and also clicking by the finger on the device is a standard behaviour but repeatedly hovering the mouse on input on the website is not really comfortable.

Comment: In summary, I got two equivalent options, to click and to write. On website both available would be good, on the device, only one would be more user-friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to focus an input field if you don't want to write in it? Otherwise you can check with
    `var isMobile = Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent);`
if the user agent is mobil before you take the focus.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior of device.
You can use some cordova plugin (like this [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard)) to hide the keyboard.
Don't forget to check out if the user agent is from a mobile device

Anyway, it's the behavior of device, hide the keyboard will make your application act different from the others

Comment: Thanks :) I will look into it